# How to increase a count if all rows for a specific ID have a value in a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables:

SupportPlan

```
+-----------------------+
| ID | ClientID | RefNo |
+-----------------------+
| 1  | 25       | A001  |
| 2  | 78       | B002  |
+-----------------------+
```

SupportPlanGoal

```
+-------------------------------+
| ID | SupportPlanId | GoalName |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  |  1            | Goal 1   |
| 2  |  1            | Goal 2   |
| 3  |  1            | Goal 3   |
| 4  |  2            | Goal 4   |
+-------------------------------+
```

SupportPlanAction

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID | GoalId | DateCompleted |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 1      | 2019-01-01    |
| 2  | 1      | 2019-01-10    |
| 3  | 2      | 2018-10-10    |
| 4  | 2      | NULL          |
| 5  | 3      | 2018-03-04    |
| 6  | 4      | NULL          |
+-----------------------------+
```

Each plan has a number of goals, and each goal has a number of actions. What I would like to do is have a count of "Completed Goals" from each support plan. A completed goal is one where all actions have a DateCompleted value.

So in the above case Support Plan 1 has 2 completed goals out of a possible 3 and Support Plan 2 has 0 completed goals out of a possible 1.

I have attempted to use

```
SELECT GoalId, MAX(CASE WHEN CompletedActions = TotalActions THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status
FROM (
SELECT GoalId, 
       COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY GoalId, 
       CASE WHEN DateCompleted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY GoalId) AS CompletedActions, 
       COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY GoalId) AS TotalActions
FROM SupportPlan sp
INNER JOIN SupportPlanGoal spg
  ON sp.Id = spg.SupportPlanId
INNER JOIN SupportPlanGoalAction spga
  ON spg.Id = spga.GoalId
) a
GROUP BY GoalId, CompletedActions, TotalActions
```

to get the count of rows for each goal to then compare that to the total rows available, then if they are equal then the goal is complete. I am working towards the following output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Date Commenced | Goals In Place | Goals Completed | Latest Review Date |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-01-01     |  3             |  2              | 2019-01-01         |
| 2018-02-02     |  1             |  0              | 2019-02-02         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(The Date Commenced will be taken from a timestamp and the review date will be taken from another table)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the actions before doing the `JOIN`.  Then you can do the rest of the calculations.

```
SELECT sp.Id, 
       COUNT(spg.id) as num_goals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN spga.num_actions = spga.num_completed_actions THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as goals_completed,
       COUNT(spa.DateCompleted) as num_actions_completed
FROM SupportPlan sp LEFT JOIN 
     SupportPlanGoal spg
     ON sp.Id = spg.SupportPlanId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT spga.GoalId, COUNT(*) as num_actions,
             COUNT(spga.DateCompleted) as num_completed_actions,
             MAX(spga.DateCompleted) as max_datecompleted
      FROM SupportPlanGoalAction spga
      GROUP BY spga.GoalId
     ) spga
     ON spg.Id = spga.GoalId
GROUP BY sp.Id;
```

I have no idea where the review date is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't now why but I assumed that using multiple aggregations in one sub-query wouldn't work correctly :S I removed the num_actions_completed from the main query and got it to work correctly, thank-you. The ReviewDate is a field in a table called SupportPlanReview, where I will be getting the latest date available for that specific support plan.